# Send property to seda queue

Tags: apache-camel

I have a route from which I am trying to call a seda queue. I wanted to use a property which has been set in my current route to the seda queue. The below is the piece of code that I have been used, but it doesn't seems to be working as expected.

```
    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
      <route id="route1">
       <!-- Method initialize the JobDetails class with values jobName="jobTest" and jobMode="mode1" -->
       <bean ref="jobDetails" method="createJobDetails"/>
       <to uri="activemq:queue:myqueue?disableReplyTo=true" />
     </route>

     <route id="route2">
      <from uri="activemq:queue:myqueue" />
      <convertBodyTo type="my.package.JobDetails" />

      <setProperty propertyName="JOB_DETAILS">
        <simple>${body}</simple>
      </setProperty>

      <recipientList>
        <simple>direct-vm:testDirect-${property.JOB_DETAILS.jobName}</simple>
      </recipientList>
     </route>
</camelContext>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
 <route id="route3">
    <from uri="direct-vm:testDirect-jobTest" />
    <!-- Some business logic based on the job mode-->
    <setProperty propertyName="JOB_MODE">
        <simple>mode1</simple>
    </setProperty>

    <to uri="seda:testSeda?blockWhenFull=true" />
  </route>

  <route id="sedaRoute">
    <from uri="seda:testSeda?concurrentConsumers=5" />
    <log message="Message from firstRoute: ${property.JOB_MODE}" />
    <!-- Perform some business logic based on the job mode -->
  </route>  
 </camelContext>
```

Appreciated help!!!

Comment: Which version of Camel? I usually write exchangeProperty.XXX .

Comment: Nothing is inserting an exchange into your first route. What is not working - could you be more specific about what you do see?

Comment: @SteveHuston: I am setting one property(MESSAGE_TO_SEDA) in my first route and trying to read that from a seda component. But I am not able to get that inside the seda component route.

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti: I am using camel version 2.15.1 The code I have provided is inside my camelContext

Comment: It's possible I'm just not understanding your case, but please try this. In your first route, before setProperty, insert this line: <from uri="timer:foo?repeatCount=1"/>

Comment: @SteveHuston: I have edited my code for more clarity on the issue.

Comment: Could you please explain what you are seeing and what is not working?

Comment: Basically I am doing a batch processing. In my first route I'll receive huge number of data, so I am sending those information to a queue along with the job name and mode. I am passing this job mode information across the different routes. In my queue processing route I have some business logic to do based on this mode. After the processing, I need to perform some operation concurrently for that I am using seda concurrent thread. But I am unable to get the mode value in my seda processing route, i.e., <route id="sedaRoute">. My question is how to get that property value in the seda route?

Comment: Uhmm different camel contexts..... why? I use SEDA all the time and this is not difficult to do but I need context around the two camel contexts.

Comment: @Namphibian: There are other piece of codes involved in different context file,and defined different xml files also. My problem is I am not able to get the property in my second context. Could you please provide a solution if you would have gone through such a scenario earlier?